# if statement in for loop prints multiple times

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am searching the 2d array for 3 numbers and the third number is not in the array and when it outputs to the user that the number is not in the array it prints it 10 times and im guessing because the for loop goes up to 10. How can I get the statement "8675 is not in the array" to only print out 1 time.

```
public class MultiDimensionalArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] oned = {
            { 1115, 7307, 1004, 8820, 4322, 2286, 6183, 8455, 5569, 9930 },
            { 1155, 7749, 8582, 1180, 4463, 3107, 8838, 9842, 2308, 3453 },
            { 6229, 5449, 1967, 2501, 9610, 5600, 6996, 7375, 5629, 35 },
            { 6677, 2464, 5017, 5881, 639, 2772, 3465, 8718, 7747, 5621 },
            { 1646, 8533, 4250, 8119, 8163, 1236, 4433, 4093, 7834, 3037 },
            { 7069, 6522, 9604, 1609, 5725, 6255, 438, 274, 7978, 3358 },
            { 6631, 3401, 5975, 108, 3696, 2773, 1697, 9803, 7056, 4996 },
            { 7109, 4895, 5930, 7634, 7070, 5265, 7456, 5223, 9725, 368 },
            { 1201, 7776, 9000, 8654, 9635, 922, 2932, 4814, 1624, 1062 },
            { 7561, 6587, 7398, 4254, 5797, 7325, 4368, 5830, 8937, 5726 },
            { 7740, 8238, 7761, 6142, 4643, 7416, 2062, 5563, 1298, 7899 },
            { 1868, 6088, 3071, 7563, 7780, 2714, 7081, 2565, 3086, 766 },
            { 2284, 9931, 8664, 7248, 6768, 5657, 8404, 807, 7357, 2204 },
            { 9911, 6832, 8167, 546, 2709, 2046, 8465, 4171, 1841, 6106 },
            { 2123, 9005, 406, 6873, 3848, 4760, 2912, 1504, 9052, 270 },
            { 8700, 8182, 1153, 1154, 9288, 8227, 6165, 7257, 7908, 1769 },
            { 7355, 3880, 390, 1496, 6984, 7553, 981, 8049, 6948, 7312 },
            { 830, 4777, 5100, 897, 9941, 8513, 9318, 3146, 5298, 8452 },
            { 6678, 6535, 1471, 5225, 5513, 1912, 624, 8802, 5331, 4675 },
            { 4916, 2517, 4604, 4947, 9973, 9347, 9390, 8633, 60, 8983 },
            { 9977, 2505, 8436, 1285, 472, 568, 8696, 5198, 5630, 5087 },
            { 6287, 4834, 6184, 3761, 7922, 3163, 6836, 6621, 3338, 6575 },
            { 7105, 5863, 5113, 1346, 1223, 7733, 1323, 2301, 3021, 8612 },
            { 2976, 282, 271, 8111, 1320, 3441, 7129, 513, 4564, 7278 },
            { 3916, 7150, 9606, 8058, 7533, 8106, 539, 977, 32, 1074 },
            { 5859, 6361, 7489, 8347, 9441, 8281, 7728, 7944, 5272, 1598 },
            { 6078, 4624, 634, 9183, 7772, 6187, 3565, 4912, 2875, 8405 },
            { 1031, 1679, 8287, 689, 4855, 6386, 8616, 8608, 2842, 4986 },
            { 3321, 5150, 1410, 3159, 1328, 30, 191, 7133, 2797, 5334 },
            { 8610, 5512, 8141, 1398, 5918, 2641, 9014, 4475, 4590, 8672 } };

    // Is 8227 in the array?

    int number = 8227;
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 30; column++) {
             if (oned[column][row] == number)
             {
                 System.out.println("8227 is in the array");
             }
        }
    }

// Is 9911 in the array?

    int check = 9911;
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 30; column++) {
             if (oned[column][row] == check)
             {
                 System.out.println("9911 is in the array");
             }
        }
    }

// Is 8675 in the array?

    int look = 8675;
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 30; column++) {
             if (oned[column][row] == look)
             {
                 System.out.println("8675 is in the array");
             } 
             else if (oned[column][row] != look)
             {
                 System.out.println("8675 is not in the array");
             }               
        }
    }
}
}
```

The output that i get is

```
8227 is in the array

9911 is in the array

8675 is not in the array

8675 is not in the array

8675 is not in the array

8675 is not in the array

8675 is not in the array

8675 is not in the array

8675 is not in the array

8675 is not in the array

8675 is not in the array

8675 is not in the array
```

Comment: You only need one loop block to check all the numbers

Answer (score 1):

**Your way:**

```
int look = 8675;
boolean found = false;
outer:
    for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 30; column++) {
             found =(oned[column][row] == look);
             if(found){
                 break outer;
             }
         }
     }

 if(found){
       System.out.println("8675 is in the array");
 }else{
       System.out.println("8675 is not in the array");
 }
```

"found" will only be true, if you found the value. If you found the value you can "leave" your loops using the break command. It quiets the outer for looop using the lable "outer". You can change the lable however you want.

After that, you can just check the boolean, if you found something and print the Text you want.

**Better way:**

A better way to to it would be to write a function:

```
public boolean searchInArray(int[][] src, int find){
    for(int[] row : src){
        for(int num : src){
            if(num == find){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can now call that function like this:

```
boolean hasValue = searchInArray(oned, 8227);
```

The function is iterating over every int array in your 2d array using a for loop. Inside the for loop it is iterating over each element of the 1d int array. If the element is equevalent to the one you search it will return true. Otherwise it will return false after it searched the whole 2d array.

You can now use the variable hasValue to print your text:

```
boolean hasValue = searchInArray(oned, 8227);
if(hasValue ){
   System.out.println("8227 is in the array");
}else{
   System.out.println("8227 is not in the array");
 }
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would make this answer even better.

Comment: @tobias_k of course ;) I just pressed enter to early :D

Comment: @Conner no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this :

```
   public void searchInt(int number){

    int[][] array= {
        {1115, 7307, 1004, 8820, 4322, 2286, 6183, 8455, 5569, 9930},....};

    for (int[] nmbres: array) {
      for (int num : nmbres) {
        if (number== num) {
          System.out.println(number +"is in the array");
        }
      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add two  breaks  to the code to break the for loops[image]